# Pandas: import csv with user corrected faulty values

Tags: python, csv, pandas, user-input, converters

I try to import a csv and dealing with faulty values, e.x. wrong decimal seperator or strings in int/double columns. I use converters to do the error fixing. In case of strings in number columns the user sees a input box where he has to fix the value. Is it possible to get the column name and/or the row which is actually 'imported'? If not, is there a better way to do the same?

```
example csv:
------------
description;elevation
point a;-10
point b;10,0
point c;35.5
point d;30x


from PyQt4 import QtGui
import numpy
from pandas import read_csv

def fixFloat(x):
    # return x as float if possible
    try:
        return float(x)
    except:
        # if not, test if there is a , inside, replace it with a . and return it as float
        try:
            return float(x.replace(",", "."))
        except:
            changedValue, ok = QtGui.QInputDialog.getText(None, 'Fehlerhafter Wert', 'Bitte korrigieren sie den fehlerhaften Wert:', text=x)
            if ok:
                return self.fixFloat(changedValue)
            else:
                return -9999999999

def fixEmptyStrings(s):
    if s == '':
        return None
    else:
        return s

converters = {
    'description': fixEmptyStrings,
    'elevation': fixFloat
}

dtypes = {
    'description': object,
    'elevation': numpy.float64
}

csvData = read_csv('/tmp/csv.txt',
    error_bad_lines=True,
    dtype=dtypes,
    converters=converters
)
```

Comment: You can convert most of these values to floats using `df['elevation'] = df['elevation'].astype(float)`, your problem is the value '30x' what is this supposed to be?

Comment: 30x is an example value for a accidentially set string into an numeric column. Cause it's very hard to say what the real value looked like, the user should choose or fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over them, the built-in `csv.DictReader` is pretty handy. I wrote up this function:

```
import csv
def read_points(csv_file):

    point_names, elevations = [], []
    message = (
        "Found bad data for {0}'s row: {1}. Type new data to use "
        "for this value: "
    )

    with open(csv_file, 'r') as open_csv:
         r = csv.DictReader(open_csv, delimiter=";")
         for row in r:
             tmp_point = row.get("description", "some_default_name")
             tmp_elevation = row.get("elevation", "some_default_elevation")

             point_names.append(tmp_point)            
             try:
                 tmp_elevation = float(tmp_elevation.replace(',', '.'))
             except:
                 while True:
                     user_val = raw_input(message.format(tmp_point, 
                                                         tmp_elevation))

                     try:
                         tmp_elevation = float(user_val)
                         break
                     except:
                         tmp_elevation = user_val

             elevations.append(tmp_elevation)                

    return pandas.DataFrame({"Point":point_names, "Elevation":elevations})
```

And for the four-line test file, it gives me the following:

```
In [41]: read_points("/home/ely/tmp.txt")
Found bad data for point d's row: 30x. Type new data to use for this value: 30
Out[41]: 
   Elevation    Point
0      -10.0  point a
1       10.0  point b
2       35.5  point c
3       30.0  point d

[4 rows x 2 columns]
```

Displaying a whole QT dialog box seems way overkill for this task. Why not just a command prompt? You can also add more conversion functions and change some things like the delimiter to be keyword arguments if you want it to be more customizable.

One question is how much data there is to iterate through. If it's a lot of data, this will be time consuming and tedious. In that case, you may just want to discard observations like the '30x' or write their point ID name to some other file so you can go back and deal with them all in one swoop inside something like Emacs or VIM where manipulating a big swath of text at once will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a different approach here.
Rather than at read_csv time, I would read the csv naively and **then** fix / convert to float:

```
In [11]: df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, sep=';')

In [12]: df['elevation']
Out[12]:
0     -10
1    10,0
2    35.5
3     30x
Name: elevation, dtype: object
```

Now just iterate through this column:

```
In [13]: df['elevation'] = df['elevation'].apply(fixFloat)
```

*This is going to make it much easier to reason about the code (which columns you're applying functions to, how to access other columns etc. etc.).*

Comment: If there is a large amount of data, and if some of the incorrect formatting implies to reject that data, then processing it after loading will be very inefficient. And if the proportion that needs to be modified is high, this is also much less efficient than adjusting the data on the same single pass when it is read in.

Comment: @EMS Not sure I agree with your use of "very" and "much", I'd give you "may"... Often it's faster to read from csv using faster c-engine, rather than the slower python-engine (which you have to go down if you're munging with python functions). I agree __if__ the proportion of bad data is *high* and you're wanting to reject it, then it's more space-efficient to do in one pass... but that seems like an unusual case tbh.